# How to print python dictionary values to a txt file

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dictionary

{'1': a, '2': b, '3': c, '4': d}

I want to unpack it and print a,b or c,d ... etc..

I can print ab in two lines but i want them on the same line separated by a ',' and written to a csv is possible

```
for key, value in dict.items():
                if key =="1" or key == "2":
                    print(value)
```

Comment: The question seems to be unclear. Can you post what output you expect from the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is something that you are looking for -

```
dict = {'1': 'a', '2': 'b', '3': 'c', '4': 'd'}


# Create an empty string to store values from dict
result_string = ""
for key,value in dict.items():
  if key == '1' or key == '2':
    # add the current value from dict to this string
    result_string =  result_string + value + ","

# this will print: a,b
print(result_string[:-1])
```

Comment: glad that it helped. Can you upvote and accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the csv.DictWriter class directly to write dict data into csv files

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}

with open('f.csv', 'w') as csvfile: 
    fieldnames = list(d.keys()) 
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames) 
    writer.writeheader() 
    writer.writerow(d)
```

Comment: in my case I would like to write the results of print(result_string[:-1]) from the previous response